# htaccess making appear root index.php on all pages

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I wanted to redirect www.jainmunilocator pages to jainmunilocator.org, so I added the following code to my htaccess in root directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.jainmunilocator\.org$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/jainmunilocator\.org\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^130\.211\.190\.222
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.jainmunilocator.org/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]
```

But this gave birth to another issue. Now whenever I open subdirectory/ It shows the root index.php content. How to avoid that?